# Excel April prior to a date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking for a succinct formula that will output prior 01/04/yyyy (datevalue) for any given date - so:

```
A1: 31/05/2023     B1: 01/04/2023 (formula calculated, datevalue 45017)
A2: 22/03/2024     B2: 01/04/2023 (same formula as above)
A3: 01/12/2021     B3: 01/04/2021 (same formula as above)
A4: 01/01/2022     B4: 01/04/2021 (same formula as above)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the formula below on cell B1:

```
=IF(MONTH(A1)>=4,DATE(YEAR(A1),4,1),DATE(YEAR(A1)-1,4,1))
```

Drag it down to fill the other cells.

[image: Results]

Comment: I think this one will fail for 01/04/xxxx itself though. Or rather, it will pick the 01/04 of previous year, and that may not be wanted, which can be solved by adding a nested if checking for 01/04 itself.

Comment: @LPChip With the current formula, 01/04/xxxx will remain 01/04/xxxx instead of 01/04/(xxxx - 1). Not sure if the OP wants the previous year or no with this case.

Comment: It's fine, thanks